# How to change the order of non-numeric variable on the x-axis for a long data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a long data frame and would like to make an x-y plot with three groups. The x variable is not numerical and when it is plotted it follows a particular order. I would like to change that and instead of plotting the data in the sequence {002}, {011}, {10-2}, {100} to plot it in the sequence
{002}, {011}, {100}, {10-2} i.e. reverse the 3rd and 4rd positions on the x-axis.

What would be the best way to re-arrange the values programatically as my real data frame is much longer.

Thank you!

```r
set.seed(129)

df_long <- data.frame(x=c('{002}', '{011}', '{100}', '{10-2}', '{002}', '{011}', '{100}', '{10-2}', '{002}', '{011}', '{100}', '{10-2}'),
                      type=rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), each=4),
                      value=rnorm(12))

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = x, y = value, group = type)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = type)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = type))
```

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but I would remove the "-" with `gsub` if this occurs frequently. With this you ensure the alphabetically order of your data and I would simply overwrite the x-axis with a custom character vector containing original names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the limits of a discrete scale determine the order of the breaks and this can be given a function, you could use an anonymous function to reverse the 3rd and 4th values.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(129)

df_long <- data.frame(x=c('{002}', '{011}', '{100}', '{10-2}', '{002}', '{011}', '{100}', '{10-2}', '{002}', '{011}', '{100}', '{10-2}'),
                      type=rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), each=4),
                      value=rnorm(12))

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = x, y = value, group = type)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = type)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = type)) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    limits = function(x) {
      x[3:4] <- x[4:3]
      x
    }
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @teunbrand, that works really well. I was wondering also how would you change the position of two x's that are not next to each other let say {002} and {100} and is it possible to be done in the same function i.e. two changes?

Comment: Yes sure you can do `x[c(1, 4)] <- x[c(4, 1)]` to swap the first and fourth one. You can make the function as complicated as you want, as long as the output can be recognized as one of the x-axis categories.